# How to add every group of odoo in my dropdown?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo

.py code:

```
from openerp.osv import fields,osv
from openerp import http

 class group_js(osv.osv):
    _name = "group_js"
    _description = "Group JS"
    _columns = {
        'js': fields.text('Javascript',required=True),
        'active': fields.boolean('Active'),
        'group_ids': fields.selection(usergroup,'Groupname',required=True),
```

XML code:

```
<field name="active"/>
<field name="group_ids" string="Group" />
<field name="js" placeholder="Enter your Javascript::"/>
```

So please give me the function defination, that's why I use in my module.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of selection , you should be use many2many or many2one field . i am using many2many field in my answer .

```
'groups': fields.many2many('res.groups', 'js_group_rel', 'js_group_id', 'group_id', string='Groups'),
```

automatically all groups add in your field and you select more then one at a time . when you want to show in drop down so add a widget in xml file

```
<field name="groups" widget="many2many_tags"/>
```